# Multiple unique string replacements using character start and ending positions

Tags: javascript

I have a text string:

```
Google is a search engine created by Larry Page and Sergey Brin.
```

And a nested array of named entities:

```
[["Google","ORG",0,5],["search engine","PRODUCT",12,24],["Larry Page","PERSON",37,46],["Sergey Brin","PERSON",52,62]]
```

I want to replace each occurrence of a named entity with an html element, something along the lines of replacing `Google` with:

```
`<div class="ner-tag">${named_entity[i][0]} <span class="ner-tag-type">${named_entity[i][1]}</span></div>`
```

However, if I do these one by one, then the overall character positions will change, so unless I track those as well, I won't be able to use these. At times, you will get a string that has both something like `Google` and `Google Docs` and these are different entities, so I can't easily do a simple global replace.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by sorting the array with the replacement info descending based on the indexes, here is an example:

```js
const str = 'Google is a search engine created by Larry Page and Sergey Brin.';
const replacements = [["Google","ORG",0,5],["search engine","PRODUCT",12,24],["Larry Page","PERSON",37,46],["Sergey Brin","PERSON",52,62]];

replacements.sort((a, b) => b[2] - a[2]);

const result = replacements.reduce((a, replacement) => {
  return a.substring(0, replacement[2]) + replacement[1] + a.substring(replacement[3] + 1)
}, str);


console.log(result);
```

Comment: ahh, so simple! makes sense!